# NextJS & Bulma SASS Not updating variables

Tags: sass, next.js, bulma

Hey folks hope all is well. I can't seem to get Bulma to properly import into NextJS and allow me to modify variables if I import any utilities. I am sure I am doing something wrong though. Here is what I have in my globals.sass:

```
@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all"

$sand: #efb396
$info: $sand

@import "~bulma/bulma.sass"
```

So with this code, no variables change at all. But if I remove that first line:

```
$sand: #efb396
$info: $sand

@import "~bulma/bulma.sass"
```

It works just fine. Whats the deal? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override any of the Bulma's Sass variables, you need to set them *before* actually importing Bulma.

```css
$sand: #efb396;
$info: $sand;

@import "~bulma/sass/utilities/_all";
@import "~bulma/bulma.sass";
```